# how to set shortcut for CtrlPBuffer, just like ctrl-p for CtrlP

Tags: buffers, plugin-ctrlp

question for CtrlP users

I have ctrl-p mapped to open file from the filesystem. I want to map ctrl-y to open a buffer that is already opened.

how should I change my vimrc? does anyone know?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

this one works for me

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-y> :CtrlPBuffer<CR>
```